# Python: Is it possible to setup a folder trigger?

Tags: python, file

I would like to monitor the directory using python. Whenever there is a new file the program will notify the user.

Current I am using a loop, which run os.listdir, to poll the directory regularly. However this is very inefficient. Is there any way that I could setup some software trigger (in Python) to enhance the efficiency?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html for Windows and http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-fam/ for Linux. Also, you can check out https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/, which is multi-platform.